# How do I schedule a job in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have to schedule a job using [Schedule](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/schedule) on my [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) web application.

```
def new_job(request): 
   print("I'm working...")   
   file=schedulesdb.objects.filter (user=request.user,f_name__icontains ="mp4").last()    
   file_initiated = str(f_name)  
   os.startfile(f_name_initiated)
```

I need to do it with filtered time in db

```
GIVEN DATETIME = schedulesdb.objects.datetimes('request_time', 'second').last()
schedule.GIVEN DATETIME.do(job)
```

Comment: try [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django is a web framework. It receives a request, does whatever processing is necessary and sends out a response. It doesn't have any persistent process that could keep track of time and run scheduled tasks, so there is no good way to do it using just Django.

That said, Celery (http://www.celeryproject.org/) is a python framework specifically built to run tasks, both scheduled and on-demand. It also integrates with Django ORM with minimal configuration. I suggest you look into it.

You could, of course, write your own external script that would use schedule module that you mentioned. You would need to implement a way to write shedule objects into the database and then you could have your script read and execute them. Is your "scheduledb" model already implemented?

Comment: I was checking celery , I guess it can custom job at predefined time

Comment: I was checking celery , I guess it can run custom job at predefined time CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'every-second': {
        'task': 'example.say_hello',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=5),
    },
} I need something which can run job  at specific time given by user...

Comment: I am pretty sure that it is possible to schedule tasks in celery in runtime. Anyway, if you already have scheduledb model and it can serialize/deserialize into schedule objects, you can write a stand-alone script to read the schedules from the database, and then sleep and run tasks in a loop. The schedule page you linked has a very primitive version right there.